# WSL2 nativescript-vue Unable to apply changes ECONNREFUSED livesync

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-vue, wsl-2

**Environment**

CLI: 7.0.12

Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2)

**Details**

After running `tns run android`, the app compiles properly but not hot reloading. Got an error:
Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: **connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:40547**

After using `--log trace`, found that port 40547 (changes every run), in this particular run, is related to livesync, maybe.

```
Result when throw error is false:
{ stdout: '40547\n', stderr: '', exitCode: 0 }

spawn: /home/user/android/platform-tools/adb "-s" "emulator-5554" "shell" "rm" "-rf" "/data/local/tmp/org.nativescript.application-livesync-in-progress"
Result when throw error is false:
{ stdout: '', stderr: '', exitCode: 0 }
Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:40547.
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:40547
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 40547
}
Will emit event runOnDeviceError with data {
  projectDir: '/home/user/code/vue-ns',
  deviceIdentifier: 'emulator-5554',
  applicationIdentifier: 'org.nativescript.application',
  error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:40547
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 40547
  }
}
Stopping webpack watch for platform android.
Webpack process exited with code null when we expected it to be long living with watch.
```

**To Reproduce**

`tns run android`

**Expected behavior**

Hot Reload.

**Additional context**

Trying to setup nativescript-vue in windows wsl2. Made it to work. It compiles correctly. For reference, I used the following write-ups/articles to set it up.

1. [react-native-app-in-wsl2](https://gist.github.com/bergmannjg/461958db03c6ae41a66d264ae6504ade#enable-access-to-adb-server-from-wsl2)
2. [Using the Android emulator on Windows 10 with WSL2](https://medium.com/@pellea/using-the-android-emulator-on-windows-10-with-wsl2-39c2bae30c49)

I only used the basic app template from vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template.

`tns doctor`

```
✔ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
✔ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
✔ The Android SDK is installed.
✔ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
✔ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
✔ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
✔ Local builds for iOS can be executed only on a macOS system. To build for iOS on a different operating system, you can use the NativeScript cloud infrastructure.
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 7.0.12 version and is up to date.
✔ Component @nativescript/core has 7.0.13 version and is up to date.
✖ Component @nativescript/ios is not installed.
✔ Component @nativescript/android has 7.0.1 version and is up to date.
```